# Methods for multi-language web applications in PHP

Tags: php, string, internationalization, multilingual

I am trying to build a web application with multiple languages, just for my leisure/study. I am wondering if there's a better way than this.

## Environment

- PHP only. no framework or library so far.

## Situation

English and Japanese sentences have different order of words, so I don't think simple concatenation like `$user_name . 'decapitated' . $enemy.` will work.

So I am thinking of saving all the sentences to database.

`+----+------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| id | en                                 | ja                                |
+----+------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| 1  | $username has decapitated $enemy.  | $username は $enemy の首をはねた！ |
+----+------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+`

Texts inside have some variables like `$username` to be replaced with `str_replace()` later.

`` $result = str_replace('$username', $username, $db->select('SELECT ja FROM `tb_language` WHERE id = 1;')) ``

## Questions

- I tried to find smarter way to expand variables in database text but I could not.  Any suggestion?
- The procedure above inevitably repeat `str_replace()` as many as variables and it seems not efficient.  Any suggestion?

Any suggestions are welcome and thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to roll your own templating system, it seems like a valid approach.  More than the `str_replace()` calls, I'd worry about the constant database lookups.   It's not really relational data.  At the very least it would cache well.  Granted, with no load, the database querie would perform perfectly fine.

Comment: Thank you Dan, yes, the constant database lookups are my concern, too.  I'm not so experienced that I cannot judge how much troublesome it is.  I imagine language.txt file maybe better solution.

Comment: I think a language.txt is a great solution, if it works for you.  It would work well with the suggested solution below (`printf()`); you could put the template themselves into the language files.

Comment: Right at now I am assuming several template file may share the same sentence, so I thought outsourcing the language file. But I will reconsider with your idea.  Thanks for your comment again.  I really appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`printf()`/`sprintf()` family of functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

`printf`, `sprintf`, `vsprintf`, *(and so on...)* functions are used for formatting strings and as such they enable you to utilize a pretty standardized set of placeholder logic.

---

What you want to have stored in your database is something like this:

`%s has decapitated %s.`

In PHP you can format this using, for example, the `printf()` function *(which directly outputs the result)* or the `sprintf()` function *(which **returns** the result)*.

```
$translated = sprintf("%s has decapitated %s.", "red", "blue");
echo $translated;

red has decapitated blue.
```

---

If you need to **specify the order** of the arguments passed in, you can do it by specifying the position. Ie. in english `$format = "%1$s has decapitated %2$s."` and in some other language something like `$format = "%2$s has been decapitated by %1$s."`.

You can use this when you want to have different order of inserted words, but *you want to keep the order same in your source code*.

Both of the these `$format` strings will be correctly formatted via the same `sprintf($format, "red", blue")` call:

- `red has decapitated blue.`
- `blue has been decapitated by red.`

Possible formatting options are nicely presented here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: Thank you Smuuf, my teacher had told me something about printf() but I have never thought over it seriously. This sure will work.